# How to display axis borders only (no grid lines) in chartjs?

Tags: chart.js

So I only want to show the axes border lines - and hide the grid lines. This is using the latest version of the chart.js package (2.9.3) and I have replicated my issue in a simplified [Codepen](https://codepen.io/ericfurspan/pen/pooxYzJ) shown below:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
type: 'scatter',
data: {
  labels: [4, 0],
  datasets: [{
    data: [
      { group_name: "Group A", x: 4, y: 25 },
      { group_name: "Group B", x: 0, y: 0 },
    ],
  }],
},
options: {
      legend: { display: false },
      scales: {
        yAxes: [ {
          type: 'logarithmic',
          scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'Active %', fontSize: 15 },
          position: 'left',
          gridLines: { display: false, drawBorder: true },
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            max: 50,
            maxTicksLimit: 4,
            padding: 10,
            callback: value => `${value.toLocaleString()}%`,
          },
        } ],
        xAxes: [ {
          type: 'logarithmic',
          position: 'bottom',
          scaleLabel: { display: true, labelString: 'User Count', fontSize: 15 },
          gridLines: { display: false, drawBorder: true },
          ticks: {
            min: 0,
            maxTicksLimit: 6,
            padding: 10,
            callback: value => value.toLocaleString(),
          },
        } ],
      },
    }
});
```

Any help or insight is appreciated; the settings I'd expect to work from the docs don't seem to be working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solved it (sort of). When I downgrade to chart.js `2.8.0` the chart borders now display as expected. With `2.9.3` the borders were not showing at all, regardless of chart type.

Answer (score 5):

You can put this options in gridline properties:

```
xAxes: [{
        gridLines: {
          display: true,
          drawBorder: true,
          drawOnChartArea: false
        }
     }]
```

Source: https://www.chartjs.org/samples/latest/scales/gridlines-display.html

Answer (score 3):

```
gridLines: { drawBorder: true, lineWidth: 0 }
```

Comment: While this code may resolve the OP's issue, it is best to include an explanation as to how your code addresses the OP's issue. In this way, future visitors can learn from your post, and apply it to their own code. SO is not a coding service, but a resource for knowledge. Also, high quality, complete answers are more likely to be upvoted. These features, along with the requirement that all posts are self-contained, are some of the strengths of SO as a platform, that differentiates it from forums. You can edit to add additional info &/or to supplement your explanations with source documentation.

Comment: This works for me. For those who don't know where to add this option,  it's options: { scales: yAxes: [{ gridLines: { drawBorder: true, lineWidth: 0 } }] }. Here's the link to Grid Line configuration https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/axes/styling.html#grid-line-configuration